# Obtaining the average of three columns per row in SQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate

The `AVG()` function in SQL works particular column data. But here, we want to calculate the average of three such columns for each row. In math, we would do

```
AVG=(col1 + col2 + col3)/3
```

Similarly: is there any query to calculate `AVG(col1, col2, col3...)`?

Answer (score 9):

If the columns aren't nullable then simply using

```
(col1 + col2 + col3)/3
```

will work fine (though on some RDBMSs you might need to have a non integer numerator or divisor to avoid integer division).

For nullable columns you might want to use something like

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL THEN 
         ( COALESCE(col1, 0) + COALESCE(col2, 0) + COALESCE(col3, 0) ) / 
            (CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
             CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
             CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       END
```

On SQL Server you could also use

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT AVG(Col)
        FROM   (VALUES(Col1),
                      (Col2),
                      (Col3)) V(Col)) AS col_average
FROM   YourTable
```